# Solving $e^{4x}+3e^{2x}-28=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

How to solve this equation:

> $$e^{4x}+3e^{2x}-28=0$$

I don't know how to solve this problem. I read over another example, $e^{2x}-2e^x-8=0,$ and it said that $e^{2x}$ is $e$ to the $x$ squared, so $e^{2x}=e^{{x}^{2}}$. Why is this so? So $e^{4x}=e^{{x}^{4}}$?

Please help me to solve it.

Comment: It is $(e^x)^2$, not $e^{x^2}$...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ok thanks, why is like that?

Comment: $e^{x^2} = e^{x\cdot x}$ is different from $e^{2x} = e^{x+x} = e^x \cdot e^x = (e^x)^2$

Comment: In general, $e^{x}\cdot e^y = e^{x+y}$. Letting $x=y$, $e^x\cdot e^x = e^{2x}$

Comment: If it were true that $e^{2x}=e^{x^2}$, then when $x=3$ we'd get $e^6=e^9$, which is nonsense.  But $e^{2x}=(e^x)^2$ is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\eqalign{e^{4x}+3e^{2x}-28=0&\implies (e^{2x})^2+3(e^{2x})-28=0\\&\implies e^{2x}=\ldots\\&\implies x\:\:\:=\ldots}$$

And I think what "$e$ to the $x$ squared" means is $(e^{x})^2$, in this case it is equal to $e^{2x}$ since one have $(a^{m})^n=a^{mn}.$

Comment: Thanks, but can you elaborate a bit on why it is written as a trinomial?

Comment: @user437158 See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\Big(e^{2x}\Big)^2 + 3e^{2x}-28=0
$$
$$
u^2 + 3u - 28=0
$$
This is a quadratic equation.  Once you've found $u$, you've got $e^{2x}$.  After that, find $x$.

Comment: +1 This is how I was going to approach it. I think the introduction of $u=e^x$ is the best way to explain this to someone who is having trouble. However, it might be nice to mention that you are using the substitution $u=e^x$, perhaps at the beginning of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $e^{2x}=(e^x)^2$, but neither is equal to the "$e^{x^2}$" that you mentioned. 
So no, $e^{4x} \not= e^{x^4}$, but rather $e^{4x}=(e^4)^x$.

Therefore, $e^{4x}+3e^{2x}-28=0$ means $(e^{2x})^2+3(e^{2x})-28=0$.

Let $m=e^{2x}$, and you well get an auxiliary trinomial of $$m^2+3m-28=0.$$ If you factor your auxiliary trinomial, you will have $$(m+7)(m-4)=0.$$ Given the roots of $m=-7$ and $m=4$, can you solve for $x$ from here?

Comment: $(m+7)(m-4)=0$, and then what do I do? thanks

Comment: wouldn't I need to use $\ln$ since it is $e^x$? how would I do that?

Comment: @user437158 If $ab=0$ then either $a=0$ or $b=0$. Use this fact to solve for $m$, only then you can get an expression of the form $e^{2x}=\text{number}$ which can be solved using $\ln$.

Comment: So $\ln(e^{2x}+7)\ln(m-4)$?

Comment: @user437158 Forget the $e^{2x}$ part for now, can you solve the equation $(m+7)(m-4)=0$ for $m$?

Comment: $m=-7$ or $m=4$

Comment: @user437158 Then replace $m$ by $e^{2x}$ you get $e^{2x}=-7$ or $e^{2x}=4$. Can you solve those two last equations now for $x$?

Comment: @Hakim Yes, $2x=\ln(4) \implies x=ln(2)$. The other one must not have any real solutions...

Comment: @user437158 Exactly, good job! ;)

Comment: @Hakim thanks for your help and time.

Comment: @user437158 You're welcome, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

$$(e^{2x})^2+3(e^{2x})-28=0.$$
$$e^{2x}=y$$
$$y^2+3y-28=0$$
$$y_{1,2}=\frac{-3\pm11}{2}$$
$$y_1=4=e^{2x},2x=\ln 4$$
$$x=\ln2$$
for $$y_2=-7$$ no real solutions